# UICollectionViewCell disappear when I scroll them infinitely

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying infinite scrolling for 30 rows which will appear again

My code starts from importing

```swift
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate{
```

Here's my collectionView

```swift
let imageCollectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2
        collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 123, height: 123)
        collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        collectionViewFlowLayout.invalidateLayout()

        let imageCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
        imageCollectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        imageCollectionView.register(ImageCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "imageCollectionViewCell")
        imageCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return imageCollectionView
}()
```

`viewDidLoad()` method includes

```swift
imageCollectionView.delegate = self
imageCollectionView.dataSource = self        
self.view.addSubview(imageCollectionView)
```

Setting the layout programitically

```swift
func setLayout(){
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            imageCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            imageCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            imageCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            imageCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)

     ])
}
```

Setting CollectionView functions

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfItemsPerSection
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let collectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        collectionViewCell.imageView.backgroundColor = .green
        collectionViewCell.imageView.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return collectionViewCell
}
```

To make infinite scrolling I tried this method

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if indexPath.row == numberOfItemsPerSection - 1{
                numberOfItemsPerSection += 30;
                imageCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
}
```

I read online to include this function but nothing happened

```swift
func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

[Working application link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9G6k.gif)

Comment: What you want to achieve? are you trying to reload collectionveiw with pagination or in the partition?

Comment: In am trying to load in pagination